# UISwitch only working one way

Tags: ios, uiswitch

I have a `UISwitch` which I placed in my storyboard and have connected it to an outlet in my implementation file, and connected the `valueChanged:` method to the control event "value changed". However, it is only called when I switch it from off to on, and not from on to off.

Here's my code:

ViewController.h

```
@interface splitViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *tipIncluded;

@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
- (IBAction)valueChanged:(UISwitch *)sender {
    NSLog(@"3");
    if (_tipIncluded.isOn==YES){
        NSLog(@"2");
        _tipIncluded.on=NO;
        _tip.text=@"";
        _tip.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    }
    if (_tipIncluded.isOn==NO){
        NSLog(@"1");
        _tipIncluded.on=YES;
        _tip.text=@"0";
        _tip.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        _tip.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }

}
```

I know that it is only calling this method when it turns from off to on because I only get the 3 from the NSLog at the end of the method when I switch it that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never compare anything with YES or NO:

```
if (_tipIncluded.isOn==YES){
if (_tipIncluded.isOn==NO){
```

That code is wrong. Also there is no `isOn` property of a UISwitch.

Simplify your code. Just say `if (_tipIncluded.on)` and `else` (or `if (!tipIncluded.on)`).

Also what you are doing is nuts. The *instant* the user switches the switch to ON you are switching it to OFF *immediately* and vice versa. This will make it impossible to move the switch!

Comment: There is indeed an "isOn" property on UISwitch.
The property is declared as `@property(nonatomic,getter=isOn) BOOL on;`

Comment: OK but it's exactly the same as saying `on`, no?

Comment: Very true, just thought I'd point out that the code that uses `isOn` isn't _wrong_ ;)

Comment: so, the problem was that before I knew that there was a 'on' property, I was using another BOOL value to keep track of when it was on or off, so I had to switch its value everytime. Just had to stop switching to make it work. Ty very much.

Answer (score 0):

And remember to put an outlet on the switch too. This has worked for me. Just make sure to put a default value first. ON maybe.

```
[mySwitchOutlet setOn:YES animated:YES];

- (IBAction)mySwitch:(UISwitch *)sender {

    if ([sender isOn])
    {
         NSLog(@"ON");

    }else{
         NSLog(@"OFF");
    }

}
```